# Is there is limit on the number of `AppIntentRecommendation`

Tags: watchos, appintents

Is there is limit on the number of `AppIntentRecommendation` that we can return in the `recommendations()` delegate function (shown below)?
watchOS 10 RC seem to limit this number to 15 and truncates if the length of the returned array is larger than 15.

```
func recommendations() -> [AppIntentRecommendation<ConfigurationAppIntent>] {}
```